# Autocomplete Material UI search based on two attributes

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have this data:

```
const sample = [
    {hero: 'DARTH VADER', faction: 'EMPIRE'},
    {hero: 'LUKE SKYWALKER', faction: 'REBEL'},
    {hero: 'GREEDO', faction: 'BOUNTY HUNTER'},
];
```

Using Autocomplete, I am able to search the value via either *hero* or *faction* attribute by assigning one of them in `getOptionLabel={(option) => {option.hero}}` or `getOptionLabel={(option) => {option.faction}}` prop.

However I would like to be able to search using both of these attributes at the same time (typing either DARTH VADER or EMPIRE will return the same result).

The questions are as follows:

1. Can I achieve that using a single autocomplete?
2. If not, can we use a toggle to change which attribute to look for in the autocomplete?

Many thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Autocomplete provides the `filterOptions` prop.

you can use it to provide a custom filter like so (here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-41mlr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)):

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'any',
  stringify: (option) => option.hero + option.faction,
});

export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      options={sample}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.hero}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Custom filter" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}

const sample = [
  {hero: 'DARTH VADER', faction: 'EMPIRE'},
  {hero: 'LUKE SKYWALKER', faction: 'REBEL'},
  {hero: 'GREEDO', faction: 'BOUNTY HUNTER'},
];
```

Comment: Great! It really helped a lot. It allows you to search multiple values in mui auto-complete. By default, it will use search in the single field only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getOptionLabel attribute like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      options={sample}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.hero} ${option.faction}`}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Custom filter" 
         variant="outlined" />
      }
    />
  );
}

const sample = [
  {hero: 'DARTH VADER', faction: 'EMPIRE'},
  {hero: 'LUKE SKYWALKER', faction: 'REBEL'},
  {hero: 'GREEDO', faction: 'BOUNTY HUNTER'},
];
```

Comment: Nice option as well!

Comment: This is throwing errors